# Selenium Chrome Driver: NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/collect/Lists Exception

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have the following code:

```
    public static final String _DRIVER_PATH = "c:\\Users\\Public\\Downloads\\chromedriver.exe";

    .....

    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", Constants._DRIVER_PATH);

    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
```

My dependencies are:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.0</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Then I get on the last line:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/collect/Lists
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions.<init>(ChromeOptions.java:74)
    at com.FlashMain.main(FlashMain.java:39)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.collect.Lists
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 2 more
```

I run on Windows 10, ChromeDriver.exe version 2.29 and Chrome - 58.0.3029.110

You advise is appreciated.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Use Selenium version 2.x , Selenium 3.0 chromium implementation is different

Comment: You were right! thank you! But how can I still use the latest selenium driver?

Comment: @Subrata Fouzdar How is this helpful for someone, who wants to use selenium3?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you're using both selenium and other library that brings google common library with version that is not compatible with latest selenium.
Build [dependency tre](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/resolving-conflicts-using-the-dependency-tree.html)e using:

```
mvn dependency:tree
```

Exclude old version by [managing exclusions](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html) and add new one directly or simply try to update library that refers to old version of google common.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this recently using Selenium with Spring Boot, and the [webdrivermanager](https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager) maven plugin.  The problem was that I used the latest webdrivermanager version, but relied on the selenium-java version provided by Spring Boot, which was a few versions back.  If you find yourself in a similar scenario, the solution is quite easy, override the spring boot version for your Selenium dependency and make sure you are using consistent and appropriate versions!